# Descargar imagen desde telegram-cli

Tags: imagen, telegram

Tengo instalado telegram-cli y me gustaria tener un fichero con el historial y sus ids.

El caso es que si el id de la foto es 0500000001ac06470c000000000000009f9379d5d9093964

si hago:

```
history xxxxxx 10
load_photo 0500000001ac06470c000000000000009f9379d5d9093964
```

Me lo descarga bien, pero si me salgo y ejecuto

```
./telegram-cli -W -N -D --permanent-msg-ids -e "load_photo 0500000001ac06470c000000000000009f9379d5d9093964"
```

No se guarda, y si me meto de nuevo en telegram y directametne hago

```
load_file 0500000001ac06470c000000000000009f9379d5d9093964
```

Sin haber hecho antes el history, no me lo baja tampoco.

¿A que es debido?

Gracias

Comment: será que el `history` carga los id en memoria?

Comment: Buenas

Si, eso pienso, pero conoces alguna forma de almacenarlo y/o usarlo de nuevo en el siguiente comando.

o de usar dos ejecuciones de telegram_cli a la vez

He probado con \n \\n espacios ; && || y nada

Answer (score 0):

**Telegram download POC** con `bash`

Listado de ficheros **"epub+zip"** del canal **NOMBRECANAL** (cuidado con los nombres de canal y UTF-8), importante dar tiempo a que cargue los `id's`

```
EPUB=$( (sleep 10;echo "history NOMBRECANAL 100 0";sleep 2;echo "quit") |telegram -C -W --enable-msg-id --permanent-msg-ids|grep "epub+zip"|awk '{print $1}')
```

Extracción de ficheros y descarga, importante dar tiempo a que cargue los `id's`

```
(sleep 10;echo "history NOMBREDE CANAL 10 0";sleep 2;for FID in $EPUB
do
        echo "load_file $FID"
        sleep 1
done)|telegram -C -W --enable-msg-id --permanent-msg-ids
```